# Macro is clearing cells in other sheet when there is no instruction to do so

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting the following bug.

I have two macros one in Module 1 and other in Module 4 Named "RestricPref" and "TailoredInputs" respectively. Now "TailoredInputs" is supposed to make changes in the "Inputs" sheet only I have used `With` command to do that but for unknown reason it's making changes in the "Preferences" sheet also.

To understand the problem better please run the Module 1 first and see the changes in "PreferencesTab" and then Run Module 4 and you will find that it changes data in "PreferencesTab" when it's not supposed to do so.

Can anyone find the bug?

Module1 code which runs fine:

```
Option Explicit
Sub RestrictPref()    
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Preferences")

With ws
'Set to No
Range("C11").Value = "No"
Range("C13").Value = "No"
Range("F11:H11").Value = "No"
Range("F13:H13").Value = "No"
Range("C17:E17").Value = "No"
Range("C19:E19").Value = "No"
Range("C23:H23").Value = "No"
Range("D27:H27").Value = "No"
Range("C31:F31").Value = "No"

'Clear Contents
Range("D11:e11").ClearContents
Range("D13:e13").ClearContents

'Set C27 to Yes
Range("C27").Value = "Yes"

End With
End Sub
```

Module 4 code generating the bug:

```
Option Explicit
Sub TailoredInputs()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i, j, l As Integer, rngHide As Range

    Set ws = Sheets("Inputs")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ws
    ws.Range("A7:A200").EntireRow.Hidden = False

    For j = 10 To 152
        If ws.Cells(j, "J").Value = "H" Or ws.Cells(j, "K").Value = "H" Then
            For l = 4 To 9
                If ws.Cells(j, l).Interior.ColorIndex = 19 Then
                      If Cells(j, l).MergeCells Then
                         Cells(j, l).MergeArea.ClearContents
                      Else
                         Cells(j, l).ClearContents
                       End If
                Else: End If
            Next l
            'build the range which will be hidden
            If rngHide Is Nothing Then
                Set rngHide = ws.Cells(j, 1)
            Else
                Set rngHide = Application.Union(rngHide, ws.Cells(j, 1))
            End If

       Else: End If
    Next j

    'anything to hide?  Hide it.
    If Not rngHide Is Nothing Then rngHide.EntireRow.Hidden = True

    With Sheets("Inputs")
    .Select
    .Range("Spendinginput").Select
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the references to the Cells property, like the following, need to be prepended with a dot.

This:

```
Cells(j, l).ClearContents
```

needs to be this:

```
.Cells(j, l).ClearContents
```